How do I automate transferring files daily from SFTP Server that requires Putty PPK private key file to authenticate?
I am trying to find a solution to move files from our third party's SFTP server which requires to use ppk file to authenticate.
I am able to go into that SFTP server manually by putting host name, user name, pointing to a PPK file and then putting a passphrase.
But, I need to come up with a solution to schedule to go in there on a daily basis and grab files.
I am using Windows VM and WinSCP.
I previously used a batch file code (using WinSCP), but I got a hostkey so it was pretty straightforward process.
For example:
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://testuser:T3sdyhigmcBfZPdr@ftpus.pointclick.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 
1024 xx:d1:fd:0e:c5:xx:de:d7:3c:xx:27:xx:a3:4d:9f:64" 
synchronize local F:\FTP2 /logs
exit

I have not used PuTTy before, and I am not sure how to process a ppk file using a script / some other automated process.
How do I approach this task?
Update (7/29):
This is script that I used (with little modification for confidentiality) - I put bottom script in one line:
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command "open 
 sftp://BEE.SFTP@sftp.xxx.com/ -passphrase=\"R&A_sftp2024\" - 
 privatekey=\"F:\NHFTP\nh20240703ver2.ppk\"" "option confirm off" 
 "cd /uploads" "put F:\NHFTP\DataExtracts\SampleArchive.7z" "exit"

This is error message I got on 7/29
 Message
 Executed as user: SQL2\JDoe. C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program 
 Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com" /command "open 
 sftp://BEE.SFTP@sftp.xxx.com/ -passphrase=\"R  & A_sftp2024\" - 
 privatekey=\"F:\NHSFTP\nh20240703ver2.ppk\"" "option confirm off" 
 "cd /uploads" "put F:\NHSFTP\DataExtracts\SampleArchive.7z" 
 "exit"Searching for host...Connecting to 
 host...Authenticating...Using username "BEE.SFTP".Password:Access 
 denied.  Password: Connection has been unexpectedly closed. 
 Server sent command exit status 0.  Authentication log (see 
 session log for details):  Using username "SFTP".  Access 
 denied.     Authentication failed.  'A_NH_sftp2024\" - 
 privatekey=\"F:\NHSFTP\nh20240703ver2.ppk\""' is not recognized 
 as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch 
 file.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.


You didn't close the quotes after C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.com.

@MartinPrikryl  I tried again with adding a quote after winscip.com, but still getting an error. I updated the post with script that I used today and error message that I got today. BTW, what is purpose of having "SampleArchive.7z"? Is this name of 7z file that we are creating to put the output data? Ty.

It seems that your WinSCP commandline is really broken into multiple lines (not just posted this way for readability purposes). Everything needs to be on one line! + In your put F:\NH\DataExtracts\SampleArchive.7z command, you are trying to upload that specific file. That's all we know about the file name.

And additionally you have the inner quotes wrong. Again, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax

@MartinPrikryl Regards to F:\NH\DataExtracts\SampleArchive.7z, I am not sure what you meant by "trying to upload that specific file." Basically what I am trying to do is, I am trying to move files from this SFTP to let's say F:\NH\DataExtracts\ folder. Also, I am not sure where quotes are wrong - where are inner quotes?

@Java I'm not that proficient with the whole quotes syntax in WinSCP and it drives me crazy as well. I wonder if this is something that ChatGPT/Copilot/Claude could help you with? As for the SampleArchive.7z that is a file that you would upload, from my example. You can see that we are uploading (put) a file to the SFTP server.

@Java Check this Pastebin I created for you: https://pastebin.com/d8EQNbsy

@pmdci  Thank you so much. Greatly appreaciated. I tried first by putting all script in one line. I am getting "Password: Access denied" issue. When I separate lines into 6 lines (like the Pastebin), task keeps just running without stop. I updated the script that I used and error message on the updated post content. Do we have to put script in one line by the way?

@pmdci I think the issue is that I am trying to download files, not upload. But the script says "Uploads", and that could be the issue. When I looked at the https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline , there is /synchronize parameter. I think that might be the solution possibly. How do I script to get all files /synchronize from "/WH_BE" (remote SFTP Server) to local "F:/NH_SFTP" folder? Thanks.

@Java I think it must be one line. The line breaks were just formatting output of the Microsoft Copilot. I find WinSCP syntax to be dreadful. I was hoping that you could use some AI to fix it for you. Yes in my case it simpler because: a) I had no spaces in my paths and filenames; and b) I had a single upload command.

So it seem that you have multiple problems. 1) Using the private key 2) Downloading (instead of uploading). Focus on one of them only.

According to the documentation -privatekey=file and if passphrase is needed -passphrase=valueorfile depending on optional -passwordsfromfiles . Of course having the passphrase stored for unattended use means that if anyone gets access to your computer or files they have access to the server. Alternatively you could use puttygen to change the PPK file to have no passphrase and then just use it, which is equally risky.
Or WinSCP will (always AFAIK) automatically use any keys loaded in 'pageant' which is the agent process installed with or as part of Putty, and which reads PPK files specified at startup or by right-clicking the taskbar icon (a desktop computer with a black hat on top that I think is intended to look like the old MAD Magazine "Spy vs Spy"). Then you only need to enter the passphrase (if any) once as long as your system doesn't reboot, shutdown, or crash.

I have a solution that that uses WinSCP (not the GUI, but the CLI that comes with it) instead of PUTTY. Since you mentioned using it before, I'm assuming this would still be an option for you. Here is the format of the command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>winscp.com /command "open sftp://<username>@sftp.server.com/ -passphrase="<passphrase>" -privatekey="D:\ssh_keys\my_sftp_key.ppk"" "option confirm off" "cd /uploads" "put D:\DataExtracts\SampleArchive.7z" "exit"

It is a one-line command, so it is quite long. Here is a more visual explanation:

I'm my case I'm uploading files to the SFTP server, but I'm hoping you can see from this example how to adapt the command to your needs. The important bit (i.e., authenticate with a .PPK keyfile) works.
PS: See comments below. Apparently my quotes for passphrase and passkey work because I have no spaces in those, but they're not correct even though they work. See here for more information.

You have the quotes around private key and passphrase wrong. It can work only if there are no spaces in the passphrase and private key (and then you do not need the quotes at all). See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax

@MartinPrikryl Thanks. Since it has been working for me (no spaces in my passphrase or private key) then I have not noticed it. But I hope the OP will see your comment and look at the syntax. I might add the details.

@pmdci I tried and getting an error. Please see the edited post for the details of error message. Can you possibly edit the image on the top with right space  or quotes? Sorry for asking too much. Thank you.

@Java Check this Pastebin I created for you: https://pastebin.com/d8EQNbsy
